# how to model a relation between 2 OR 3 items?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have 3 tables: Groups, Rules, Actions

I can have a relation between (1 group, 1 rule), (1 group, 1 action) or (1 group, 1 rule, 1 action)

I guess I could create a linking table group_rule_action and set one of the FK as NULL if it's a relation between only two of the items

For instance, I have a relation between group 1 and rule A, I'd have (1, A, NULL)

The problem is that if I create an action for this group/rule, I'd have to **update** this relation to (1, A, ACTION1)... but if I add a new action later on, I need to **insert** (1, A, ACTION2), so it's not very consistent

I could also set a groupId FK both on Actions and Rules, but then when I link an action to a rule, I'd need to make sure they have the same groupId (and I'd end up having redundant information)

Any better ideas?

Comment: Have three tables connecting them: (1) Group_Rule, (2) Group_Action, and (3) Group_Rule_Action. There are presumably important semantic differences between a group that's associated with a rule and a group that's associated with an action, and between either of those and a group that's associated with both a rule and an action. You don't state whether a single group can be associated with just one rule or whether a single group could be associated with many rules; ditto for groups and actions; ditto for groups, rules and actions. The specification is incomplete. But optionally null fields 

Comment: make `action` related with `rule` then `rule` related with `group`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, there isn't really an important semantic difference, it's just about the order of insertion... the user must first create a group, then he can create rules and actions for this group, and then he can relate the rules to the actions (N to N)

Comment: @EkoDedy, this doesn't help because then I can't create an action without first having a rule (which is one requirement)

Comment: Your requirement would be clear if you specify functional and multi-valued and other dependencies. In any case, I think you do not want the inconsistency of resorting to update a table in some cases and insert into the table in some other cases. Then why insert a row with NULL for A first of all? If G -> R, G -> A and GR -> A are valid in your case, then have 3 tables (G,R), (G,A) and (G,R,A) and insert a tuple in the last table only if GR->A is true for a set of three values so that you do not need to update the table later.

Comment: How many actions can be connected to one group/rule combination? If only 1, you shouldn't have to INSERT to connect an action to an existing group/rule combination.

Answer (score 0):

As you say,

> I could also set a groupId FK both on Actions and Rules…

I take that to mean that groups and rules, as well as groups and actions, are related as "one to many": one group can have many rules/actions, one rule/action can belong to one group only. If that is so, then do use the `groupId` columns for those relationships.

Now to establish a many-to-many relationship between rules and actions with the restriction that a rule and an action being related must belong to the same group, you'll *have* to introduce some redundancy – specifically, to duplicate the information about the group the two entities belong to.

In view of that, a third table, `RulesActions`, could be defined like this:

```
RuleID
ActionID
GroupID
FOREIGN KEY (RuleID, GroupID)
FOREIGN KEY (ActionID, GroupID)
```

The `GroupID` column is the redundant bit: obviously, either `RuleID`'s or `ActionID`'s group can be determined by looking up the corresponding table. However, as you can see, the single `GroupID` column is used to serve as the group reference for both, thus making sure the two items will have the same group. And to make sure the group ID is indeed the one that both the rule and the action belong to (and not just an arbitrary one), the column is included in both foreign keys, i.e. the `RulesActions` table references `Rules` by `(RuleID, GroupID)` instead of only by `RuleID`, and same for `Actions`.

Of course, given such FK definitions, corresponding primary keys or unique constraints in the target tables need to be defined in the same way. I say *primary keys **or unique constraints*** because in the product I am working with, SQL Server, foreign keys are allowed to reference columns that are either defined as the primary key or applied a unique constraint to. In SQL Server, therefore, I could define the `Rules` and `Actions` tables like so:

- `Rules`:

  ```
  RuleID   PRIMARY KEY
  GroupID  FOREIGN KEY
  UNIQUE (RuleID, GroupID)
  ```
- `Actions`:

  ```
  ActionID  PRIMARY KEY
  GroupID   FOREIGN KEY
  UNIQUE (RuleID, GroupID)
  ```

and that would allow me to have the `RulesActions` schema specified earlier. I'm not sure if many other products would allow that, and if not, you could try the following approach instead:

- `Rules`:

  ```
  RuleID   UNIQUE
  GroupID  FOREIGN KEY
  PRIMARY KEY (RuleID, GroupID)
  ```
- `Actions`:

  ```
  ActionID  UNIQUE
  GroupID   FOREIGN KEY
  PRIMARY KEY (RuleID, GroupID)
  ```

This way the UNIQUE constraints are applied to the (entity) ID columns only, to ensure uniqueness of the IDs, and the target column sets of the foreign keys in `RulesActions` are defined as primary keys, so that you have a common FK <-> PK relationship.

Please note that the idea itself would change very little if it turned out that you needed many-to-many group/rule and/or group/action relationships. For a many-to-many relationship, you would need to introduce a mapping table where an `EntityID, GroupID` would be the primary key, and the corresponding foreign key would need to reference *that* table instead of the main entity one.